# Pointing subdomain to root with WordPress on root - Redirection issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed on example.com.

I am making a multi-lingual site, with English on the main root domain and french on a sub domain:

```
fr.example.com
```

The way i'm setting it up involves just the one WP installation (on the main domain), and have the sub domain point at the root of the main domain.

So, in cPanel, I have set up the sub domain's document root to be the same as the main domain (/public_html).

The problem is that I am getting redirected to example.com when I visit fr.example.com.

The hosting tech support told me I am doing it correctly in cPanel, so it must be the code of WP that is redirecting the visitor to the main domain.

I'm not sure if this is the .htaccess file or something with the PHP of WP.

Does anyone know what my problem is and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I last built a site like this, the mapping of the domains did not come out of the box - I had to use a domain mapping plugin to tell WordPress how to handle requests that came in on another domain.  It would appear that this is still the case. The one I used is here: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/.  If you already have a mapping in place, it might be worth re-visiting the Permalinks page in order to remind Wordpress of this.